# Get the accuracy of an MKMapView Location

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, userlocation

I was wondering if there's a way to obtain the accuracy of a received location from an MKMapView.

I would have thought the following code would work but it doesn't. Can I log the property directly as well?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {    

    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyBest) {
        NSLog(@"Best");
    }
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation) {
        NSLog(@"Best for nav");
    }
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters) {
        NSLog(@"100m");
    }
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer) {
        NSLog(@"km");
    }
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters) {
        NSLog(@"10m");
    }
    if (userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers) {
        NSLog(@"3km");
    }    
}
```

A circle usually represents the accuracy of a location by wrapping it round the small blue circle so the accuracy is obviously being sent.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I applied the same logic but used verticalAccuracy when the horizontalAccuracy was not returning a valid result.  What I found was that:

Accuracy Key: 
 -1.000000 = BEST, 
 -2.000000 = NAV, 
 10.000000 = 10m, 
 100.000000 = 100m, 
 1000.000000 = 1km, 
 3000.000000 = 3km

and the result obtained from the map (using simulator) was: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `horizontalAccuracy` property in `CLLocation` indicates how accurate the *current instance* of the coordinates are.

It is not the "desiredAccuracy" (the property that can be set and read in `CLLocationManager`) that the map view is using.  As far as I know, that setting is not accessible in the `MKMapView`.

However, in the Breadcrumb sample app, in the [BreadcrumbViewController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_BreadcrumbViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Classes_BreadcrumbViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) file there is this comment:

```
// Note: we are using Core Location directly to get the user location updates.
// We could normally use MKMapView's user location update delegation but this does not work in
// the background.  Plus we want "kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation" which gives us a better accuracy.
```

So this implies that the `MKMapView` is at least not using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`.

Comment: Yes, i've set the desired accuracy to BestForNavigation but obviously this accuracy is not guaranteed.

So i would need to obtain the user's location through CLLocationManager to get the accuracy of the user's current location? Seems a little pointless to me. (more memory, power).

Answer (score 0):

Is this delegate method called at all? Make sure you have set `showsUserLocation` to YES for the `MKMapView` instance

Comment: Yes, this method is being called.